# Problem with namespace packages: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python3.7 and trying to get namespace packages to work, but having some module `import` issues. It is not clear to me how to fix this. I have followed the instructions given here (1st method): [Packaging namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages)

My project is organized as follows:

```
scripts/
  python_pkgs/
       a/
          __init__.py     <-- Contents of this file are name='a'
          a.py
          b.py
       utils/
          __init__.py     <-- Contents of this file are name='utils'
          util.py
  setup.py
```

Contents of `setup.py` are:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=['python_pkgs.*'])
)
```

Now a.py is an executable script. I do the following in there:

```
#/path/to/python3 -B

from b import foo
from python_pkgs.utils import util
```

The first import works OK because b.py is in the same folder as a.py. However, I am getting an error trying to `import` `util.py`:

```
        from pythong_pkgs.utils import util, misc
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythong_pkgs'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Python will always automatically add the directory containing the main script to the beginning of `sys.path`. So put all your executable scripts in the *scripts* directory. You also need to add an *\_\_init\_\_.py* file to the *python_pkgs* directory to make it into a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pythong_pkgs` should be package recognizable by `find_packages` then there should be `__init__.py` inside this directory (see [documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#finding-simple-packages)).

Second thing is that executable script should not be part of python package. It should be separated file

```py
#/path/to/python3 -B

from python_pkgs.a.b import foo
from python_pkgs.utils import util
```

or

```py
#/path/to/python3 -B

from python_pkgs.a.a import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can also call python module `python -m python_pkgs.a.a`

Comment: Namespace packages should not require `__init__.py`. See PEP-420.

Comment: Yes, but `find_packages` requires it. for namespace package it will be required to use `find_namespace_packages` https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#finding-simple-packages. will update response

Comment: OP is using `find_namespace_packages`, see his `setup.py`.